# Laravel 5.6 - Auth::check() Failing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I used the laravel spatie backup in my system, and all my functions such as creating a new backup, deleting, and downloading are working locally. I tried to deploy my website on a free hosting, everything seems to work except the delete and download function. Upon investigating, I have seen that it fails because of the Middleware I have created for the download/delete route. Here's my StaffMiddleware where only accounts with the staff role can access it.

Middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

        if(Auth::check())
        {
            if(Auth::user()->role == 'staff')
            {
                return $next($request);
            }
            else
            {
                return redirect('/'); 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('/');
        }
}
```

Routes

```
Route::get('backup/create', 'Admin\BackupController@create');
Route::get('backup/download/{file_name}', 'Admin\BackupController@download');
Route::get('backup/delete/{file_name}', 'Admin\BackupController@delete');
```

When I try to access the download function, it redirects to the homepage since the Auth::check() line fails in my middleware. Note that I am logged in and authenticated while accessing the download function. This only happens in the live server, but all of the code works locally. Can you please help me on this one? Thanks!

Comment: is you storage/framework/sessions writable ?

Comment: I've set all the file permissions in the live server to 777

Comment: It looks like an issue with sessions and laravel doesn't log you in after the page reload. Can you try debugging the login first?

Comment: Is the user to roles relationship a one-to-one or many-to-many?

Comment: Hi @PeterMatisko, all of the routes works well, only the download function fails and redirects me to my home page

Comment: @DigitalDrifter The relationship is one to one

Comment: Sorry, hard to help without detailed debugging of your code.

Comment: Clear app cache, clear route cache, clear config cache, turn on debug, set app as local in .env then try debug app and see if there is any error or log entry.

Comment: Tried everything but still the same result. Seems that the session is being lost when I redirect to that exact route as seen in my comment in @rkj 's answer

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    //dd($user); //debug if didn't work 

    if($user && $user->role == 'staff') // if your role is coming from relation then try `$user->role->name == 'staff'`
    {
       return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: Hi, it still goes back to the dashboard page since it's being redirected to `/`

Comment: did you try to enable the debug and does it print the `user` ?

Comment: What do you mean by what guard i am using? Sorry im new to this one

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to get the user from the request

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->user() && $request->user()->role == 'staff')) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: still the same thing happening

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminMiddleware {
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next,$guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect('admin/login');
            }
        }else{
            if( \Auth::user()->role =="admin" ){
                return $next($request);
            }
        }
        return redirect("admin/login");

    }
}
```